# Jquery to remove parent container of unmatching text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to find text in a table cell that matches the text in a h1 heading then remove all of the other table rows that contain the text that does NOT match. The example below only works if I have one .tabelrow containing a .tablecell so I need to target any .tablecell to find one that matches the date in the h1 heading?  I've looked at .contains and **not(:contains**( etc but not sure how to formulate this.

```
if ( $(".heading").text() == $(".tablecell").text() ) {
//remove the parent element of the non matching strings, i.e. the outer tr
}
```

*HTML*

```
<h1>Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Fri 17 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Sat 18 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Sun 19 Jun</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get all `TD` element which doesn't meets criteria and then use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get `TR` and [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) them

Add you have to add the relevant class i.e. `heading` to `<H1>` element

```js
$(".tablecell").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() !== $(".heading").text();
}).closest('tr').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="heading">Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Thu 17 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Fri 18 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Sat 19 Jun</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I've changed data inside the table to get one element matching the title. Your example would have no matches cause the text inside `<h1>` is nowhere inside the `<table>`

```js
$('table .tablecell').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() != $("h1").text()) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Thu 17 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Fri 18 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Sat 19 Jun</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not:contains` this way:

```js
$('#bt').click(function() {
   var txtMatch = $('h1').text();
   $('td.tablecell:not(:contains("' + txtMatch  + '"))').closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
<tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Fri 18 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Fri 17 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Sat 18 Jun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="tablecell">Sun 19 Jun</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="bt">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tablecell").each(function(){
   if ( $("h1").text() == $(this).text() ) {
     //remove the parent element of the non matching strings, i.e. the outer tr
        $(this).parent('tr').remove()
    }
})

<h1>Fri 18 Jun</h1>
<table>
 <tr class="tablerow">
   <td class="tablecell">Fri 17 Jun</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="tablerow">
  <td class="tablecell">Sat 18 Jun</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="tablerow">
 <td class="tablecell">Sun 19 Jun</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each function to achieve this:

```
        <h1 class="heading">Fri 18 Jun</h1>
        <table>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td class="tablecell">Fri 17 Jun</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td class="tablecell">Fri 18 Jun</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td class="tablecell">Sun 19 Jun</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $( ".tablecell" ).each(function( index ) {
            console.log($( this ).text());
            console.log($( ".heading" ).text());
            if ( $(".heading").text() != $( this ).text() ) {
              $(this).remove();
            }
          });
        </script>
```

I hope this will help you :-)